# Definition of Power from electricity and from energy

Tags: energy, electricity, work, power

In the electricity topic, my physics book has defined Power as $P=IV$, $I$ being current and $V$ as voltage.

But then later in the Energy topic, power has been defined as $P=\frac{W}{t}=\frac{F.d}{t}$. The book also states that it is the same power we are talking about in both sections.

Therefore $IV=\frac{F.d}{t}$, But I don't see the logical link in this last equation. I think the definition from Electricity is a specific form of the definition from Energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electrical power *P(t)=I(t)·V(t)* is a time dependent *instantaneous power*, which is defined as *P=dW/dt*, and *P=W/t=F.d/t* is an expression for the mean mechanical power when a mechanical work W was done in a time t. The instantaneous (time dependent) mechanical power P(t) has, in general, to be written as *P(t)=F(t)*·*dd(t)*/*dt*=*F(t)·v(t)*. In general, you cannot equate the instantaneous electrical power to the mean mechanical power. If the instantaneous electrical power is equal to an instantaneous mechanical power, you should use the appropriate formula.

Answer (score 2):

Take $IV=\frac{dq}{dt}\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=\frac{1}{dt}dq\left(\int\vec{E}\cdot\ d\vec{l}\right)=\frac{dw}{dt}$. You can think of it as the time rate of change of the work done by the electric field on a test charge, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

**Electrical Definition**

Electric power, like mechanical power, is the rate of doing work, measured in watts, and represented by the letter $P$. The term wattage is used colloquially to mean "electric power in watts." The electric power in watts produced by an electric current $I$ consisting of a charge of $Q$ coulombs every $t$ seconds passing through an electric potential (voltage) difference of $V$ is

${\displaystyle P={\text{work done per unit time}}={\frac {VQ}{t}}=VI\,}$

**Energy Definition**

Power, as a function of time, **is the rate at which work is done**, (same definition as above). so it can be expressed by this equation:

${\displaystyle P(t)={\frac {W}{t}}}$

Because work is a force applied over a distance, this can be rewritten as:

${\displaystyle P(t)={\frac {W}{t}}={\frac {{\mathbf {F}}\cdot {\mathbf {d}}}{t}}}$

And with distance per unit time being a velocity, power can likewise be understood as:

${\displaystyle P(t)={\mathbf {F}}\cdot {\mathbf {v}}}$

Knowing from Newton's 2nd Law that force is mass times acceleration, the expression for power can also be written as:

${\displaystyle P(t)=m{\mathbf {a}}\cdot {\mathbf {v}}}$

Power will change over time as velocity changes due to acceleration. Knowing that acceleration is the time rate of change of velocity, this can then be written:

${\displaystyle P(t)=m{\mathbf {v}}\cdot {\frac {d{\mathbf {v}}}{dt}}}$

Comparing with the equation for kinetic energy:

${\displaystyle E_{\text{k}}={\tfrac {1}{2}}mv^{2}}$

It can be seen from the previous equation that power is mass times a velocity term times another velocity term divided by time. This shows how power is an amount of energy consumed per unit time.

Answer (score 0):

$$
P = IV 
= \frac{dq}{dt} \frac{dE}{dq} 
= \frac{dE}{dq} \frac{dq}{dt}
$$

The last line is merely the chain rule, so

$$ P = \frac{dE}{dt} $$

You could imagine there is an amount of charge getting to the load per unit time $(I)$, and since each charge carries an amount of energy $(V)$, the total energy delivered per unit time will be $IV$.